# iphone nav bar image question about retina

Tags: ios, retina-display, navbar

I have a navBar showing an image (320 x 44), but I don't know yet if I have to prepare as well an image double the resolution for retina display?
icons need retina resolution even for tab bar, so a nav bar needs an image what size?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will need a retina image. Retina images are always double the height and width (in pixels) of your normal image.

Comment: And that high res image needs to be the same name as the low res one but with an @2x added.